# Как отправлять запрос в django из вне?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

Добрый вечер! Суть вопроса такова, есть html страничка где то, и есть приложение на сервере на джанго, надо через ajax отправить запрос со странички к приложению и вернуть ответ. И туда и сюда с данными. Они на разных доменах и серверах валяются.

ПОкажите пример с кодом пожалуйста.

Comment: Тимофей, а вы всё же позвоните заказчику. :)

Comment: Могу дать наводку на [CROS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что написание кода за автора